# JQuery $.get() question

Tags: jquery

Ive got the following question and im trying to figure out the answer:

> > You can find the following code here:
> >     http://7.testaddress.com/test.php Do you think the code will work, explain?

```
     $.get('http://1.testaddress.com/ajax/remote.php?id='+id, responseCallback);
```

Is the answer no it wont work because its not located at the same address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it wont work because it is from a different sub-domain. At the bottom of the bottom of the  [jQuery documentation for the Get method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) there's this little chestnut:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, *subdomain*, or protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I believe JQuery has a type of ajax request called JSONP ... which would enable you to do cross domain ajax requests.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/